# update part of model

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a model class which contains 5 properties but only 3 properties are shown in the view.
When I call create action, I need to update just this 3!!

I'm trying this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "Id")]Location location) 
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid) 
        {
            db.Location.Add(location);

            bool car_in_database = db.Car.Any(c => c.Id == location.Car.Id);
            if (car_in_database)
            {
                db.Entry(location.Car).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.Entry(location.Car).Property(l => l.ClientId).IsModified = false;
            }

            db.SaveChanges();  

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

but it doesn't work.. anyone know why or what I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Only .NET 4.5 and EF 5.0 support unmarking property as not modified](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/03/24/ef5-rejecting-changes-to-a-single-property/) so if you are using .NET 4.0 you must not set entity state to modified. Instead you must manually set each property you want to modify with `IsModified = true`